# How to reduce space complexity of "isUniqueString"

Tags: c#-4.0

I Have written the following isUniqueCharsInString

```
public static bool isUniqueCharsInString(String str)
        {
            int[] charsCount = new int[256];
            for (int i = 0; i < charsCount.Length; i++)
            {
                charsCount[i] = 0;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                int val = str[i];
                charsCount[val] = charsCount[val] + 1;
                if (charsCount[val] > 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            return true;

        }
```

Although it worked well.How could i reduce its space complexity so that minimum memory could be used at run time. regards.

Comment: You do realize that this code does not work for characters outside the (extended) ASCII range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To minimize the space complexity use `byte[]` or `bool` for your `charsCount` or even better `BitArray`, since you're only using it for setting flags:

```
public static bool isUniqueCharsInString(String str)
{
    var charsCount = new BitArray(256);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        int val = str[i];
        if (charsCount[val])
        {
            return false;
        }
        charsCount[val] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

An interesting alternative approach using LINQ:

```
public static bool isUniqueCharsInString1(String str)
{
    return str.ToCharArray().GroupBy(c => c).All(g => g.Count() <= 1);
}
```

It's less optimized in both space and time, but much more concise and easy to understand.

Out of curisity: why are you so worried about space complexity? Your original implementation is only using a 1 KB array (256 * 4 B).

Comment: it was just one example in actual i was dealing an extremely large string of characters by the way your code is difficult for me to understand if you have time in future please little bit elaborate it.Thanx

Comment: @user3266922 The second one probably? It first converts the string to `IEnumerable<char>` to be able to use LINQ, then I group the collection by individual character values and in the last step I count the number of occurences for each different character, returning false as soon as one occurs more than once.

Comment: @user3266922 The space complexity of your original algrithm doesn't depend on the size of the input string. And also the time complexity is O(n), it stops as soon as it finds first duplicate character. Thinking about it: for strings longer than 256 character you can immediately return false, since there are only that many different characters available. All this makes it much more efficient than my alternative solution.

Comment: Please could you refer me a link or tutorial where i can learn IEnumerable.It really annoys me a lot since it is used by lot of people and so easily but i could not learn it use by trying again and again

Comment: @user3266922 Try searching for `LINQ tutorial` and take a pick. I find [this one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/net-linq-from-scratch--net-9507) quite nice.

Comment: That sounded promising